# I apparently can't install Manjaro or any Arch based distribution on my laptop

Tags: windows, dual-boot, manjaro

I want to install Manjaro but my laptop (ASUS X550LA-DH71) for some reason it won't let me install or even finish partitioning. It stops at 6% I'm attempting a dual-boot with Windows 10 Education

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the ISO is OK.
Follow instructions at
[Manjaro Wiki - Check downloaded ISO](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Check_a_Downloaded_ISO_Image_For_Errors)

If you are copying the ISO to a USB stick in Windows, try application called [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/).
Unetbootin and other windows applications for copying ISO to USB don't
seem to work well with arch distributions.